# Can't change Google Calendar Exchange/Office 365 sync frequency

Tags: gmail, calendar

I often get alarms for non-existing events from Calendar because it didn't receive the updates from the Zimbra server (using the  Exchange/Office 365 protocol). For instance, I had an event in my Zimbra calendar schedule at 0 minutes ago. And 150 minutes ago I received an e-mail with attached .ics that postponed this event by 6 hours. Nevertheless, I got the notification from my smartphone. When I manually hit "Refresh" the event indeed moved 6 hours forward.

In the Gmail app there's a setting to sync with the Zimbra server every 30 minute and it was supposed to sync this very event at least 90 minutes ago, but it didn't. Is there a way to solve this issue?

At the same time, the native Google Account events are always updated instantly when the phone is online and it's always online.

I have Pixel 3 XL with Android 12.

[image]